# Conditional Format not changing when formula is true/false

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following conditional formatting applied.

[image]

What I am doing is checking for sales vs goal and plan. The formulas themselves work. I know this because Row 6 works. It turns green when any of the formulas are true.

What is wrong is that I7 stays green when it is false and then B7 does not change to green when the formula is true.

Here the formula is true:
[image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I deleted the rest of the conditional formatting on the sheet to eliminate the possibility that something else was throwing this off.

Formula 1

```
=AND(I7>=E8,I7<I8)
```

Formula 2

```
=I7>=I8
```

Edit -- I added two new rules to specifically work for row 7. Any thoughts why columns I:K stay green when the rule is false?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use absolute coordinates for `I7`. i.e. use `$I$7`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad In what part? I'm not using any absolute coordinates in the formula and the other parts work fine. Then in the "Applies to" section of the Conditional Formatting, it all has absolute coordinates.

Comment: @user1530279 since you are using relative references it assumes that the formula you want in B6 is `=AND(I7>=E8,I7<I8)` It will then iterate the references across and down the range, so in B7 the formula would be: `=AND(I8>=E9,I8<I9)` and C6 it would be: `=AND(J7>=F8,J7<J8)`  If you do not want the column references to change then make them absolute.

Comment: `=AND($I$7>=$E$8,$I$7<$I$8)`, `=$I$7>=$I$8`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks! That did the trick.

Comment: @ScottCraner I added on to my question. I would prefer relative references because this table will be copy and pasted. So, I added two new rules to handle row 7. Any thoughts why columns I:K stay green when the rule is false? See my question for a new screenshot.